# Magento 2 What is the best practices to override the luma theme

Tags: magento2

I have created a custom theme, parent theme is luma. I want to override the luma theme and implement a new design on custom theme.I know the _extend.less is the file to write extended css, I have added `@layout__max-width:1170px;` in _extend.less and it's working, but not sure that how to override the top category navigation, should I override the existing less files such as _navigation.less or just add regular css code in the _extend.less file?

Answer (score 0):

When creating any new theme or module you need to define registration.php file at root of your module or theme folder.

> Always use theme name in lowercase, Because Magento used this standard
>   for theme name declaration.

You haven't any problem for keep Theme name in camelcase but use standard way is much appreciated.

You have to define registration.php file inside Magento_Theme folder, its in wrong place.

Correct diagram of theme structure will be below,

```
magento2
 |_ app
   |_ design
      |_ frontend
        |_ Custom
            |_theme
              |_Magento_Theme
                |_templates
                  |_root.phtml     - Copy of Luma
              |_registration.php
              |_theme.xml
```

Your path for registration.php is app\design\frontend\Custom\theme\registration.php

registration.php file :

```
<?php
   \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
     \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
      'frontend/Custom/theme',
      __DIR__
);
```

your theme.xml file path will be,

```
app\design\frontend\Custom\theme\theme.xml
```

theme.xml file :

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
   <title>Custom Theme</title>
   <parent>Magento/luma</parent>
   <media>
      <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image>
   </media>
</theme>
```

After all setup is completed, don't forget to run deploy command for the theme,

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Check inside your admin panel,

> Content -> Design -> Configuration

for set your custom theme.

Remove cache and check in the frontend.

**Hope it works!!**